# Don't have my values on page after submit, but they are shown in link (get method)

Tags: javascript, php, html

So i am newbie in this, so please have that in mind. :)
I made some page that should calculate distance and time after user inputs needed information (in this situation coordinates [x,y]).

After input there is submit (calculate) button that should generate new page with all input values calculated and written. I used GET method, and after submit there are all values included in new link, but page is blank like it was before input.

```
<FORM action="attack.php" method="get" >
<P style="font-size: 10pt; background-color: #99CCFF;" class="auto-style2">
<div class="auto-style2">

<LABEL>Target Village: </LABEL>
<input TYPE="text" NAME="TargetVillage" SIZE="10" MAXLENGTH="30" value="" /> 

<LABEL>X: </LABEL>
<input TYPE="text" NAME="TargetXCoord" SIZE="3" MAXLENGTH="4" value="" />

<LABEL>Y: </LABEL>
<input TYPE="text" NAME="TargetYCoord" SIZE="3" MAXLENGTH="4" value="" />

 <INPUT type="submit" value="CALCULATE" style="width: 185px; height: 54px;
  font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
```

Comment: Please include the code for the attack.php file and please also include the full form (including the submit button)

Comment: Actually, as I got it, my attack.php is the same code before and after user input, but should change values after input. (probably I am wrong about this right?) :)

Comment: this is submit button:    <INPUT type="submit" value="CALCULATE" style="width: 185px; height: 54px; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">

Comment: This is not the correct way to do it.. usually it's best to redirect to another page (attack_process.php) where all the processing happens then redirect back to the page you are in. and display everything, to display the data you must have them in your value fields something like <?php echo $target_vilage;?> etc..